# Arduino as voltage monitor shorts to ground

Tags: analogread, voltage-level, electricity

I need to monitor voltages of several DC circuits in a generator's contact box.  Whenever the generator has an alarm, a LED is lit in the box and voltage on the line drops to zero.  I successfully get readings using analogRead(), but whenever I connect a line it shorts to ground (which is shared between the contact box and the Arduino) and triggers the contact box's alarm.  I need to devise a way to monitor voltages without triggering the alarm.

Each 5V line and ground from the generator has a bus bar termination point that connects to a point in the proprietary alarm box that houses the LEDs and buzzer. I connected Arduino ground to generator ground, then used A0-A7 on a Nano to connect to individual lines on the bus bar. Arduino VCC is connected to 5V regulated DC power.

Comment: What is the voltage you are trying to measure, and how *exactly* are you wiring it up?

Comment: Matt, please edit that information into the question.  Also, say if you actually need to measure voltages or just want go/nogo signals as could be obtained using optoisolators.

Comment: Input impedance of the analog pins is pretty low. So either the signal is very very weak, or your connections/software is doing something wrong.

Comment: I can detect the signals without problem.  The issue is avoiding the short to ground when I add the arduino into the circuit.

Comment: Since I was able to read voltages between load and the shared ground using a voltmeter without tripping the alarm, I thought I could do the same with an arduino.

Comment: Please add a schematic of the circuitry. And how is the Arduino powered, battery as the voltmeter?

Answer (score 2):

A voltmeter does not have a ground reference. An Arduino plugged into the USB port would have one. Conceivably a battery-powered Arduino might work, however a safer solution would be to use an opto-isolator to isolate the voltage being tested from the Arduino. Something like this:

[image: Opto isolator]

In this case you connect the "data pin" to the thing you are sensing. If it is at 5V then the LED will conduct (taking around 7 mA) and the transistor in the isolator will drive the Arduino pin `LOW`. If the data pin goes to zero volts, the transistor will not conduct, and the 1k resistor will pull the Arduino pin `HIGH`. Thus you can detect if the pin has changed voltage.

The 560 ohm resistor is a current-limiting resistor for the LED in the isolator. A 1k resistor would probably also work, reducing the current draw on the data pin to around 3.8 mA.

Comment: I would think you could also delete the 1K resistor and use the Arduino internal pullup resistor.